# JavaScript PHP HighChart transform a PHP array to a javascript array

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I saw other posts but it doesn't work. I am a bit confused here on how I implement an array into JS from PHP...

In the PHP file (test.php) I have :

```
  $table = array();  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )  
  {

   $value=$row['value'];
   $date=$row['date'];

   $table[$value]=$date;

  }
```

And in JavaScript I have :

```
  <?php include 'test.php';  ?>

   ... 

  data: (function() {
  // generate an array of random data
   var data = [],
    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
    i;

   for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
    data.push({
     x: time + i * 1000,
     y: Math.random()
    });
   }
   return data;
```

So what I look for is to put `$value=$row['value'];` in the `y :` and `$date=$row['date'];` in the `x :` **OR** perhaps putting the entire table `$table` in the `var data` will work also .

I'm new to JavaScript, so thanks in advance..!

Comment: Best way to do it would be an ajax call, with JSON return results...but you can hack something together here...hold on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your php file....

Add a line at the bottom that converts the table to json data.
And give it a variable...

```
$table = array();  
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )  
 {

   $value=$row['value'];
   $date=$row['date'];

   $table[$value]=$date;

 }

 $jsondata = json_encode($table);
```

Then in your other file....
echo that variable into your data object, in the javascript.
Remember to remove that whole random number generating function...(its just an example)

Echoing PHP into javascript is definitely not considered good practice though.
And it would be better to actually do an ajax call to your php file, and insert like that....I'll also show you how to do ajax.

```
  <?php include 'test.php';  ?>

    ... 

   data: [<?php echo $jsondata;?>], //remove that function that was here..
   // it was just to generate random numbers for the demo
   ....
   }
```

**EDIT / UPDATE**  For ajax...

So for ajax...instead of assigning a variable to $jsondata.
Just return it like so...(in your PHP file)

```
 return json_encode($table);
```

Then for this way....you dont `include('test.php')` like you did before.
Instead you just have this script inside your $(document).ready(function(){....

```
$.getJSON('test.php', function(myJSON) {

 //and inside this function you put your highcharts stuff...
 //remove that function() that generates random data
 // And you will put the 'myJSON' return object inside the 'data':[] array...
 // Provided you have structured your data correctly for highcharts, it should work...
 //  If not.... it'll be a start, and you're well on your way to debugging it

}
```

Comment: isn't there a way to put directly `$value=$row['value'];` in the `y :` and `$date=$row['date'];` in the `x :` ?

Comment: Only if you want to display one data point....but I assume you have many, in which case you have to build an array, and put inside data[]

Comment: And yes, this will do just that, because your $table, is an array of x's and y's no?

Comment: what you end up with in that $table is a $key:Value pair, which I assume is what Highcharts wants you to provide?  I cant say since I dont know which highchart you're using

Comment: The $table is an array composed of values and dates in timestamps

Comment: Like I said....if what you put into $table, is what highcharts wants, this will work....if not....it wont.  You have to provide correct data....and if it wants a key:value pair, than it will work.  Whatever the documentation tells you you need, is how you have to build your data server side

Comment: But I've provided you the nuts and bolts of how to get the data into the chart.....the rest should be simple debugging

Comment: I'm using the Spline updating each second

Comment: Seriously????? The spline updating each second is a whole other can of worms...you have to do a setInterval on your ajax call....and is your server really generating that much data all the time??  What are you plotting?

Comment: No, I'm calling the database every minute. I already succeeded in putting live data in it and it's working, and now it's just the pre-loaded data that remains :)

Comment: oh really?  Where is the live data coming from?

Comment: And why do you need preloaded data anyways, if you're doing live calls?? also....does your query handle a certain range, cause wont the data just 'crunch up' against one side as more and more gets added?  Or is the query structured to 'move' with the data...if you know what I mean

Comment: From a very big database that contains the speed (Bit/s) of connection

Comment: Exactly, they just told me to do so, so I'm like trying not to drown in the JavaScript lol

Comment: So how exactly are you loading the live data?? ...forgive me, I dont mean to sound rude....but if you needed to ask me how to simply put static data in, how is it that you could do live data, with no knowledge of ajax etc

Comment: Yeah you're right, the query is constructed to follow the latest data

Comment: Easy, there is data every minute so the php script is executed every minute with the `$.get ('test3.php', function(data) { .. var y = data; y=parseInt(y) .. }` in a `setInterval(function().. ) ` , a good synchronization that's all it took.